# Proving equivalent statements of closed sets in metric space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. Let $$d'(x,y) = \frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$$ and $$d''(x,y) = min\{d(x,y),1\}$$

Let $X \subset M$. Prove that the following are equivalent:

(a) $X$ is closed in $(M,d)$.

(b)$X$ is closed in $(M,d')$

(c) $X$ is closed in $(M,d'')$.

This is what I've done so far. I am not sure if it's right. Also, in this course I learn closed sets before open sets, so I imagine using the open set at all is not the intended solution:

$(a)$ and $(b)$: Since $X$ is closed in $(M,d)$, the complement of $X$, $X^c$, is open in $(M,d)$. i.e. for $x \in X^c$ and $y \in X^c$ there is an $\varepsilon >0$ such that $d(x,y) \le\varepsilon$. Since $d'(x,y) = \frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)} \le \frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}$ , choose $\varepsilon_0 = \frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}$

Therefore, for $\varepsilon_0$ neighborhood of $x \in X^c$ and $y \in X^c$

$d'(x,y) \le \varepsilon_0$ so $X^c$ is open and thus $X$ is closed.

I did a similar process for $(a)$ and $(c)$

Comment: How were closed sets defined in the course? [I'm pretty sure the expected way is to show that all these metrics give rise to exactly the same convergent sequences.]

Comment: @DanielFischer  Closed sets were defined as follows: If every limit point of $X$ belongs to $X$, we say that $X$ is closed. We say that a point $x$ in $M$ is a limit point of $X$ if there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n \in X$ for every positive integer $n$ and limit of $x_n$ is $x$.

Comment: As expected then. A very similar argument shows that a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $M$ converges to $x$ with respect to $d$ if and only if it converges to $x$ with respect to $d'$ (and $d''$).

Comment: @DanielFischer then is it necessary to use epsilons at all in the proof?

Comment: You could call them $\eta$ ;-) But since convergence of a sequence is defined in terms of $\varepsilon$s, showing that convergence with respect to each of these metrics is the same requires the use of $\varepsilon$s.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you Daniel, your help is very much appreciated. Would you mind assessing my new answer?

Answer (score 0):

New answer:

We know that for all $\varepsilon >0$, there is $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that if $n \ge N$ then $d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon$ and $x_n \in X$ for all $n$.

Then $d'(x_n,x) = \frac{d(x_n,x)}{1+d(x_n,x)} < \frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}$
So take $\varepsilon_0 = \frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}$ and thus $d'(x,y) < \varepsilon_0$ and so $X$ is closed in $(M,d')$.

Is this correct? I did the same process for the other part, except taking $\varepsilon_0 = min\{\varepsilon,1\}$